# Method to sort a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists (can't be tuples since I have to generate it dynamically) and it is structured as a list of lists of one int and one float Like so:

```
[[1,1.0345],[2,5.098],[3,4.89],[2,5.97]]
```

I want to get it sorted but I have only managed to get the built in sorting function to sort it by the first element of the lists or not do anything, but I need to sort them by the second element of the list and I don't want to implement my own sorting function. So an example of what I would want is:

```
[[1,1.0345],[3,4.89],[2,5.098],[2,5.97]]
```

Could someone tell me how to get one of the built in sorting functions to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pass the `key` argument.

```
L.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: I don't think I've used `sort` since we got `sorted`. But `operator.itemgetter` is better than writing your own lambda.

Comment: @oylenshpeegul: I'm genuinely curious.  Why is operator.itemgetter superior?  My instinct is to write the lambda.  It's shorter, more general-purpose, and doesn't require an import of a module I seldom use.  itemgetter seems to be 30% faster or so, I admit, but it's unlikely this'll be a bottleneck in real code.

Comment: well I actually have to sort a list of numbers I parsed out of a file with 1.8 mil entries so the 30% speed up is appreciated in my case.

Comment: x = [[[5,3],1.0345],[[5,6],5.098],[[5,4],4.89],[[5,1],5.97]]  With a list like this is can we sort using `itemgetter()` with respect to elements in x[0][1] ?

Comment: what is "operator" over here??

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> l = [[1,1.0345],[2,5.098],[3,4.89],[2,5.97]]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> l
[[1, 1.0345], [3, 4.8899999999999997], [2, 5.0979999999999999], [2, 5.9699999999999998]]
```

Comment: x = [[[5,3],1.0345],[[5,6],5.098],[[5,4],4.89],[[5,1],5.97]] With a list like this is, how can we sort with respect to elements in x[0][1] ?

Answer (score 3):

How about using they key parameter of sorted...

```
sorted_list = sorted([[1,1.0345],[3,4.89],[2,5.098],[2,5.97]], key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This tells python to sort the list of lists using the item at index 1 of each list as the key for the compare.

Comment: That is because sorted returns a new list. Built-in .sort sorts the existing list.

Comment: @user: thank Senthil, I didn't realize that might not be understood.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm still kindda new to python and I'm used to C++ where these functions usually modify the object rather than returning a different one.