# Python - How to sort a list of lists with integers and strings by the seventh element in each list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to sort this list of lists in descending order by the value of the seventh element in the lists:

```
unsorted_list = [["a", 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8], ["b", 5, 2, 7, 1, 10, 3], 
                 ["c", 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 13]]
```

How can it be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a list of lists in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201191/sorting-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @Pi, I think I could have answered this too, but in fact the OP shows lack of motivation to google this. This why this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itemgetter`:

```
>> from operator import itemgetter
>> unsorted_list = [["a", 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8], ["b", 5, 2, 7, 1, 10, 3], 
             ["c", 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 13]]
>> sorted(unsorted_list, key=itemgetter(6))
[['b', 5, 2, 7, 1, 10, 3], ['a', 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8], ['c', 2, 6, 3, 7, 11, 13]]
```